# SQL: How to check if all IDs in a list are in a table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

first of all I am sorry if this question is too obvious, since I am quite new in SQL.

So, I have a list of IDs (variable, depending how many products the user chooses). And I want to check if all of them are in a table. If one of them is not, the result of the query should be null. If all of them are there, the result should be all the rows where those IDs are.

How can I do this?

Best regards,
Flavio

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Edit your question and tag the question with sample data and desired results.  Sample data is also helpful, as is showing how you are going to execute the query with a "list".

Comment: I am using SQLite to connect with C#.

Comment: The **list**, is it a C# element?

Comment: The list is in C#: var ids = string.Join(",", lst.Select(x => x.id).ToArray()); Then to read from SQLite, I do the query, something like: 'string prod = string.Format("select * from PRODUCT where id in ({0}) order by Name", ids);'

Answer (score 1):

Do a LEFT JOIN from the list to the table on the ID field. You'll get a null if there is no record

You can even put a WHERE clause like 'WHERE List.ID IS NULL' to only see those that aren't in the table

Edit: Original Poster did not say they were using C# when I wrote this answer

Comment: The list is in C#: var ids = string.Join(",", lst.Select(x => x.id).ToArray()); Then to read from SQLite, I do the query, something like: 

'string prod = string.Format("select * from PRODUCT where id in ({0}) order by Name", ids);'

I don't know how I can to a left join with the list this way.

Comment: Then do a FOREACH loop through the array and for each record do a List.Contains(ArrayValue). If true then continue else add it to a different list or output etc

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

Not sure if this is the most efficient but it seems like it should work.

1st it generates a count of items in the table for your list.  Next it cross joins the 1 result record to a query containing the entire list ensuring the count matches the count in your provided list and limiting the results to your list.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT count(*)  cnt
  FROM table
  WHERE ID in (yourlist)) b
WHERE b.cnt = yourCount
  and ID IN (YourList)
```

Running two in statements seems like it would be terribly slow overall; but my first step when writing SQL is usually to get something that works and then seek to improve performance if needed.

Comment: No DISTINCT needed anywhere?

Comment: So if I assume the table being queried is products, I would hope ID is the primary key such that a distinct wouldn't be needed.  If however, ID is duplicated, then yes a distinct would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of Ids into a table, (you can pass them as a table variable parameter to a Stored proc), then in the stored proc, write

assuming the list of ids from C# is in table variable @idList

```
Select * from myTable 
Where id in (Select id from @idList)
   and not exists 
     (Select * from @idList
      where id Not in 
         (Select id from myTable))
```